# How to use jQuery to detect screen size at any time to make screen changes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am a program beginner here I want to ask you a question!
My English is not very good, but I try to express my problems completely

At present, I want to make a practical one in the resolution of 768px above, when the text is more than 50 characters, the excess part can be hidden, but I hope in the resolution of 768px below, the text can be more than 100 characters in the hidden, but the effect seems to be unable to achieve, I want to ask you is there any wrong writing?

Thank you for watching my question.

```js
$(function(){
  if($(window).width() <= 768){
     let len = 100;
    $('.info_content').each(function(){ 
        if($(this).html().length >len){   
            var str=$(this).html().substring(0,len-1)+"<button class='info-more'>...showmore</button>";
            $(this).html(str);
            } 
    });
  }else{
    let len = 50;
    $('.info_content').each(function(){ 
        if($(this).html().length >len){   
            var str=$(this).html().substring(0,len-1)+"<button class='info-more'>...showmore</button>";
            $(this).html(str);
            } 
    });
  }
});  

console.log($(window).width());
```

```css
.info_content{
  width: 500px;
  border:1px solid #222;
}
.info-more{
  display: contents;
  font-weight: 500;
  color:blue;
}
.info-more:hover{
  text-decoration:underline;
}

@media(max-width:768px){
  .info-more{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="info_content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Accusamus quaerat quidem beatae, sit nesciunt facilis odio reiciendis esse maxime. Eos dolorum nesciunt odit officiis possimus quis quia officia commodi ipsa repudiandae doloribus velit sint itaque, atque veritatis eveniet? Iste minima odio earum soluta accusamus consectetur esse blanditiis enim voluptates animi obcaecati eius corporis explicabo consequuntur magni reprehenderit veritatis nemo sed perspiciatis numquam, laborum nihil excepturi a. Commodi pariatur molestiae excepturi praesentium vitae voluptate, doloribus ad consequatur esse voluptatibus placeat, nam quas officiis libero qui obcaecati. Quia ipsum molestias quis iure quasi nobis odit vero, dolorem voluptatem error corporis vitae neque!</p>
```

Comment: If you're a beginner you shouldn't use jQuery at all. You can do anything jQuery does with vanilla JS nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the JS (vanilla or jQuery) for the user interactions. Everything about how it displays should be achieved using CSS... Particularly if you want it responsive.

The key is using the `text-overflow` property and placing your toggle buttons at the right places.

```
.ellipsed{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Have a look below. I made the demo resizible for you to see that it's fully responsive.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Hide the show-less on load
  $(".info-less").hide()
  
  // To toggle
  $(".info-more, .info-less").on("click", function(){
    $(this).parents(".info-container").find(".info-content").toggleClass("ellipsed")
    $(".info-more, .info-less").toggle()
  })
})
```

```css
.info-container{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border:1px solid #222;
}
.info-content{
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.ellipsed{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.info-more, .info-less{
  display: contents;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: 500;
  color:blue;
}
.info-more:hover, .info-less:hover{
  text-decoration:underline;
}

/* Just for the resizable demo */
#page{
  position: relative;
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 4em;
  resize: both;
  overflow: scroll;
  border:1px solid orange;
}
.hint{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="page">
  <div class="info-container">
    <div class="info-content ellipsed">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Accusamus quaerat quidem beatae, sit nesciunt facilis odio reiciendis esse maxime. Eos dolorum nesciunt odit officiis possimus quis quia officia commodi ipsa repudiandae doloribus velit sint itaque, atque veritatis eveniet? Iste minima odio earum soluta accusamus consectetur esse blanditiis enim voluptates animi obcaecati eius corporis explicabo consequuntur magni reprehenderit veritatis nemo sed perspiciatis numquam, laborum nihil excepturi a. Commodi pariatur molestiae excepturi praesentium vitae voluptate, doloribus ad consequatur esse voluptatibus placeat, nam quas officiis libero qui obcaecati. Quia ipsum molestias quis iure quasi nobis odit vero, dolorem voluptatem error corporis vitae neque!<button class='info-less'>show less</button></div><button class='info-more'>show more</button>
  </div>
  <div class="hint">Resize me!</div>
</div>
```